# What is the best possible way to loop this program

Tags: python-3.5

```
count = 0
while (count >4):
    fixedcosts = float(input("Enter fixed costs: "))
    salesprice = float(input("Enter the price for one unit: "))
    variablecosts = float(input("Enter the variable costs for one unit: "))
    contribution = float(salesprice)-float(variablecosts)
    breakevenpoint = float(fixedcosts)/float(contribution)
    roundedbreakevenpoint = round(breakevenpoint)
    #Finds break even point
    if int(roundedbreakevenpoint) < float(breakevenpoint):
        breakevenpoint2 = int(roundedbreakevenpoint) + 1
        print("Your break even point is ",int(breakevenpoint2),"units")
    else:
        print("Your break even point is ",int(roundedbreakevenpoint),"units")
    #Finds number of units needed to make a profit
    if int(roundedbreakevenpoint) < float(breakevenpoint):
        breakevenpoint3 = int(roundedbreakevenpoint) + 2
        print("To make a profit you need to sell ",int(breakevenpoint3),"units")
    else:
        int(roundedbreakevenpoint) >= float(breakevenpoint)
        breakevenpoint4 = int(roundedbreakevenpoint) + 1
        print("To make a profit you need to sell ",int(breakevenpoint4),"units")
    decision = input("Would you like to restart the program?")
    if decision == 'yes' or 'Yes':
        count = count + 1
        print("This program will now restart")
    else:
        print("This program will now be terminated")
        print("Press enter to stop the program")
        quit()
```

What is the best way to loop this code? I have tried while loop but I can't seem to be able to get it to work with a yes no answer.

Comment: so show the `while` stuff you'd attempted.

Comment: Sorry i thought i had added the while code

Comment: `decision == 'yes' or 'Yes'` is never going to work. you're doing `decision == (yes or yes)` -> `decision == true`. try `if (decision == 'yes') or (decision == 'Yes')` instead.